# Get attribute in xhtml from session HTTPServletRequest

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

I am new to this so I am a little bit green in jsf based applications.I am trying to display the set attribute in dashboard.xhtml page

Here is my **servlet** class:

```
  public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {

 String username = request.getParameter("username");   
 String password = request.getParameter("password");

 LoginDAO loginService = new LoginDAO();
 boolean result = loginService.authenticateUser(username, password);
 Users users = loginService.getUserByuserName(username); 

 if(result == true ){
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", users);          
    System.out.println("user"+users.getuserName());
    response.sendRedirect("dashboard.xhtml");
 }
 else{
     response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
 }
}
}
```

**dashboard.xhtml:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
    <title>DASHBOARD</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>      
    <h:outputText value="#{user.username)}"/> 
</body>
```

But, it is not displaying anything? What am I missing? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please try to use `request.getRequestDispatcher("dashboard.xhtml").forward(request, response);`

Comment: Why do you use servlet instead of a bean?

Comment: and how should i output the value

Comment: session is available as an EL 'variable' to. See the EL list of predefined one. You can always retrieve the 'user' from that.

Comment: ok thank you all i have found a way out.I have changed to bean instead of servlet and things are looking up